# Пинг проходит только на локальные адреса

Tags: java

Пингуются компьютеры только из локальной сети, нужен пинг на сервер Гугла. В чем может быть проблема?

```
try {
    if (InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8").isReachable(5000))
        System.out.println("ping");
    else
        System.out.println("eror");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    try (Socket soc = new Socket()) {
        soc.connect(new InetSocketAddress("ya.ru", 443), 5000);
    }
    System.out.println("True");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```